# Is there any reason Google does not provide any filter beyond bare search bar?

Tags: usability, search, filter, google

I have recently used the Russian Search Engine `yandex.ru` and was impressed by their filters assisting in easier search, [see for instance, this page](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=angularjs&lr=21352&rnd=64541), here the screenshot:

[image]

Any reason Google or Bing is not doing that? I find it really nice to filter by how recent the page is, which is a pain in Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google home page is simple and uncluttered.

But, once you search for something - you can filter:

Are we missing something - or are you?

[image]

Comment: Hm ... I have now put `google.com` in my location bar and, indeed, it shows up! I was previously simply using location bar in my Chrome browser and didn't see this menu! Also now Google is much faster! Must have been some evil cacheing?

Answer (score 2):

Google does have filters.  On my mobile version, there's a list of links at the top.  The right-most says "More" and the bottom link in the drop-down list is "Search tools."  That provides filtering by date, and whether you've visited the page, etc.  (This is Google mobile, on Android.)

Here's what I see on my Android:

[image: Accessing Google Search Tools]

...and then, click on "Search tools":

[image: Time/Date Filter]

On the desktop, there is a "Search tools" link at the top of the results page, (not hidden in a menu.)

Comment: I have checked Google on Android, there is a menu at the bottom - Web, Images, ... , and More expands to Shopping, Videos, ... nothing relevant! The same on the desktop - only more Google products! I could not find any date filter (and have never seen any).

Comment: I edited my comment to add some screen images from my phone.  It's really not very intuitive on the mobile version, and I probably wouldn't have found it as easily if I hadn't known about the link on the desktop version.

Comment: I have now launched the very own Google App on the iPad, the menu is there but no "Search tools" and no "More"!

Comment: That's just strange.  I used Google Chrome and typed "Angular.js" into the address/search bar.  The first time I did it, I did have to scroll the (top) menu to the left before I could clearly see the "More" link...but I wouldn't think that would be the case on a larger screen.